# How to add a column based on a formula that retrieve data from external dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

Good afternoon ,

Assume i have a dataframe `D1` of indices :

```
3   9 15 12  8  3
9  12 18 11  9  6
12 22 23 19 16 20
16 19 22 20 13 23
18 10 16 11  7  4
23 15 21 18 14  9

D1=structure(list(c(9L, 12L, 22L, 19L, 10L, 15L), c(15L, 18L, 23L, 
22L, 16L, 21L), c(12L, 11L, 19L, 20L, 11L, 18L), c(8L, 9L, 16L, 
13L, 7L, 14L), c(3L, 6L, 20L, 23L, 4L, 9L)), row.names = c(3L, 
9L, 12L, 16L, 18L, 23L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have also a database `D2` of probabilities (dim = 24 * 24 ) :

```
D2=structure(c(NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 0.0189718128018973, 
0.294303552937154, NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.0189718128018973, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.294303552937154, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.047284597249565, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.10826822658929, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.0189718128018973, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0690701037282896, NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0290200490396767, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0217379689377885, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.033863375698564, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.0189718128018973, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, NA), .Dim = c(24L, 24L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24")))
```

Question :

In `D1` , i'm searching a way to add a column called `results` such as  :

```
D1[1,"results"]=1-(1-D2[15,9])*(1-D2[12,9])*(1-D2[8,9])*(1-D2[3,9]) 
D1[2,"results"]=1-(1-D2[18,12])*(1-D2[11,12])*(1-D2[9,12])*(1-D2[6,12])
...
```

I'm also wanting to retrieve the matrix of elements :

```
D2[15,9]  D2[12,9]  D2[8,9]  D2[3,9]
D2[18,12] D2[11,12] D2[9,12] D2[6,12]
D2[22,23] D2[19,22] D2[16,22] D2[20,22]
...
```

Is there anyway to obtain this results wit basic R / `dplyr` without using loops.

I hope my question is clear and feasable.
Thank you a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the rows of 'D1', extract the column values of 'D2' based on the values in the row and do the calculation

```
D1$results <- apply(D1, 1, function(x) 
      1 - (1 - D2[x[2], x[1]]) * (1-D2[x[3],
         x[1]])*(1-D2[x[4],x[1]])*(1-D2[x[5],x[1]]))
D1$results
#[1] 0.7519886 0.7519886 0.7169111 0.7169111 0.7519886 0.7519886
```

---

If the dimensions, changes, then create a row/column indexing to extract the values and use `prod`

```
apply(D1, 1, function(x) 1 - prod(1 - D2[cbind(x[-1], x[1])]))
#0.7519886 0.7519886 0.7169111 0.7169111 0.7519886 0.7519886
```

Also, to just extract the values, remove the `prod`

```
apply(D1, 1, function(x) D2[cbind(x[-1], x[1])])
```

Comment: @TouMou Does it change in dimensions or values?  If the values change, it doesn't matter

Comment: it could change in dimensions !

Comment: What do you mean by `then create a row/column indexing to extract the values` ?

Comment: @TouMous In your computation, you are extracting each value of the 'D2' based on row/column indexing.  By `cbind`ing it does in a vectorized way with multiple values and then we do the product with `prod`

Comment: thank you a lot . Just a last question : what is the meaning of `cbind(x[-1], x[1])` ?

Comment: It is`cbind`ing the elements except first one with the first element (this will recycle to the length)